# Pass JavaScript variable into AngualrJs ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following javascript variable defined and need to pass the **memId** value into AngularJs init function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var memId = "bb7de28f-0f89-4f14-8575-d494203acec7";
</script>   

<div id="content-header" class="mini" ng-init="getMember(memId)">
```

I am getting an error : ***memId*** is not defined.

Console shows the **memId** value inside ng-init is not getting passed in.

How can I pass in the javascript variable into ng-init?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19384128/1022697 <-- this _might_ be your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to do it in the "angular" way by using `$window`:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.memId = $window.memId;
}]);
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/qwertynl/pen/jqIrK

Comment: @94 years of age "THE SILENCE HAS FALLEN" just seems like a life alert commercial.

Comment: @qwertynl how can we handle if that variable is taking time to laod, it's showing undefined if it's not loaded

Answer (score 5):

Currently Your variables are bounded to window object. You can use Angular [$window](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.$window) to access global window object

```
// Your Global Variable defined outside angular
var memId = "bb7de28f-0f89-4f14-8575-d494203acec7";

//Define Module
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

//Define Controller
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$window',
    function($scope, $window) {
        $scope.memId = $window.memId;
    }
]);
```

Comment: `+1` oooo I was too slow in typing out my answer :-(

Answer (score 0):

For angular 2, you can achieve this by using below:

In your jQuery app, declare a variable and assign it to window object:
window.glb = "This is global".
In your angular app, add the below line anywhere before your component declaration:
declare var window: any;
Then in your ngOnInit, you can access the global variable as below:
window.parent.