# Get variable from template/view into controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Perhaps my brain is still not fully functional this morning, but what's the best or proper way to get a variable from a template/view into a controller in Angular?

Say in my view I have defined `var a = 'something'`, and I need to access that value inside the controller.

I could do `passVariable(a)` on `ng-init`, and inside the controller have something like

```
$scope.passVariable = function(param){
  $scope.a = param; 
}
```

But obviously that doesn't work, and the method doesn't seem very right either ;-)

Comment: Where the `var a` is defined? Instead of `var a ..` you can use `.value([..])` service of angularjs and inject into controllers.

Comment: It's defined in the view. It needs to be, since the variable can change from view to view. Calling `.value(...)` inside the view doesn't work, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

After you assign angular module to a variable

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
 myApp.value('a', 'something');
```

then inject into the controller

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['a','$scope', function (a,scope) {
  $scope.a = a;
```

}]);

So in your view, for example say 'a' is a user name that you want to show to the user

```
 <div ng-controller="myController">

     <div> User Name: {{a}} </div>

 </div>
```

this will render as

```
  User Name : something
```

Comment: It works when I do `myApp.value('a', 'something');` inside the controller, but how can I do it in the view?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but like stated in the question the variable must be defined inside the view, since it changes from view to view. (e.g. `var a = 'something'`). Displaying the value of the variable isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out my first idea wasn't too bad after all. I've done exactly what I was describing in my question, except the variable `a` needed to be defined within angular context, or passed directly into the function. For some reason `var a = 'something'` (in the view) wasn't getting picked up.

So the following didn't work:

```
<script>
  var a = something;
</script>
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-init="passVariable(a)">
</div>
```

but with `ng-init="passVariable('something')"`, it does.

In the controller:

```
$scope.passVariable = function(param){
  $scope.a = param; 
}
```

And here's another possible answer using $window: [Pass JavaScript variable into AngualrJs ng-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390917/pass-javascript-variable-into-angualrjs-ng-init)

With the following example: http://codepen.io/qwertynl/pen/jqIrK