# Pass Javascript variables to Angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question is in reference with this one. 
[Pass JavaScript variable into AngualrJs ng-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390917/pass-javascript-variable-into-angualrjs-ng-init)

This was asked for passing a single javascript variable being passed to the angular controller. can someone let me know how can i pass several variables from a script to controller instead of a single variable ?

Comment: The method of passing variables was explained in the other question. It is applicable both to single or multiple variables.

Comment: first, don't use ng-init, that's not what it is for.  second, why are you trying to handle variables from angular in the first place?

Comment: @Claies- The page has javascript code and we want to use angular now instead of jquery. so i was thinking of just passing the javascript variables to the controller and let the controller handle for specific models....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that your variables are not in any special scope...

```
window.var1 = true;
var var2 = "foo";
var3 = {foo: "bar"};

var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.var1 = $window.var1;
  $scope.var2 = $window.var2;
  $scope.var3 = $window.var3;
}]);
```

Basically copy-pasted from linked question. [Pass JavaScript variable into AngualrJs ng-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390917/pass-javascript-variable-into-angualrjs-ng-init)

Comment: typo. here you go. :)

Comment: can i do the reverse way too ? if i want to convert angular values to javascript values. what should be done in this case ?

Comment: simple. jus got the answer after i tried it. just have to reverse it.

Comment: this work if variable are in `file1.js` and angular model/controller in `file2.js`?

Comment: Yes, as long as `file1` and `file2` are on the same page.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly the same way. Inject the $window service on your controller and all the variables outside angular mode will be available to the controller through:

```
$scope.ControllerVariable = $window.ScriptVariable
```

Comment: can you tell me if i could do the other way around too ? if i want to pass the angular variable to javascript variable ?

Comment: simple. jus got the answer after i tried it. just have to reverse it.

Comment: Actually, all `$scope.var` variables are available in the HTML through the `{{var}}` expression, inside the tag using the directive `ng-controller`.