# Accessing variable defined in slickgrid in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, slickgrid

I have an array defined in slickgrid which captures the rows which are edited in the grid using OnCellChange event. I want to access this array in my angularjs Controller so that I can send the edited rows to backend. I have already searched for this question and I got to know that I need to use $window in my controller to access global js variable. But it's not working for me. 
I have read this
[How to access global js variable in AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383725/how-to-access-global-js-variable-in-angularjs-directive) and this http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.$window

Infact in 2nd link(above) , many people have commented that it's didn't work for them either. Can anyone please tell me what am I missing?

**Slick_grid.js**

```
var editedRows = [];
    grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function(e , args){
      var item = args.item;
      for( i=0;i<editedRows.length; i++)
            {
             if(item.employeeId == editedRows[i].employeeId)
             {
                 editedRows.splice(i , 1 , item);
                 return;

             }
                else
             {
                 editedRows.push(item);
                 return;
             }
            }
    });
```

**controller.js**

```
myApp.controller('SubmitController' ,
    ['$scope' ,'$window', function($scope , $window)    {
     alert($window.editedRows);
     $scope.editedRows  =  $window.editedRows;

    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `editedRows` may have been defined within a function scope (javascript) and hence not accesible outside.

If editedRows is your own variable you can try

`window.editedRows = [];`

Not a good solution though.

Comment: Thank you so much!! The issue was that my variable was defined inside a function scope. I just moved it outside function scope and it worked.

Comment: sorry can't upvote your answer. I don't have enough credits to do that.