# how to access the javascript variable from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, jasmine-node

I need to know to access the variable ''x" from controller

**Javascript**

```
function myCtrl() {
    var x =1;

}
```

**Jasmine**

```
describe("myCtrlsettings", function() {
       var scope ;
       var rootScope; 

       beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {                           
            scope = $rootScope.$new(); 
            ctrl =  $controller("myCtrl", {
                  $scope: scope
            });
        }));

      it(" Test ", function(){

     expect(x).toBe(1);  // what should I write here??
      } );
});
```

how to access the variable ''x" from controller?

please help me

Comment: Is there any other way, without change controller file to access variable 'x'

Answer (score 0):

change your controller to

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.x =1;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way, without change controller file to access variable 'x'

Answer (score 0):

```
function myCtrl() {
    var x =1;

}
```

You cant,x scope is the function,you cant access it from outside.Several choices.

```
function myCtrl(){
  this.x=1;
}
```

or

```
function  myCtrl($scope){
   $scope.x=1;
}
```

then

```
describe("myCtrlsettings", function() {


       beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {                           
            this.scope = $rootScope.$new(); 
            this.ctrl =  $controller("myCtrl", {
                  $scope: this.scope
            });
        }));

      it(" Test ", function(){
        expect(this.ctrl.x).toBe(1);  // what should I write here??
      } );
});
```

or

```
describe("myCtrlsettings", function() {


       beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {                           
            this.scope = $rootScope.$new(); 
            this.ctrl =  $controller("myCtrl", {
                  $scope: this.scope
            });
        }));

      it(" Test ", function(){
        expect(this.scope.x).toBe(1);  // what should I write here??
      } );
});
```

if x is meant to be private then dont test it.Test only public APIs.

Comment: Is there any other way, without change controller file to access variable 'x'

Comment: unfortunatly no.Javascript variables are function scoped.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) If a variable is declared in the local scope then You'll have to
>   pass it as a parameter to the other javascript function. 
>   2) In your case i would suggest to declare 'x' globally like this :

```
var x;
function myCtrl() {
    x =1;
}
```

Comment: yes I declared the var x as globally, how to write unit test for this . to access the variable x

Comment: `yes I declared the var x as globally,` no you didnt,x is local and private to myCrl in your question .

Answer (score 0):

simple example

HTML:

```
 <section ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      Value of global variable read by AngularJS: {{variable1}}
    </section>
```

JavaScript:

```
 // global variable outside angular
    var variable1 = true;

    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.variable1 = $window.variable1;
    }]);
```

reference: [How to access global js variable in AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383725/how-to-access-global-js-variable-in-angularjs-directive)