# Angular ng-include src containing global variable

Tags: angularjs

I have a variable that is defined globally, and I need it in an angular expression.
I tried using the [`$window`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/docs/api/ng.$window) service but it doesn't seem to work:

**JS**

```
var INCLUDE_FILENAME = 'includeme.html';
```

**HTML**

```
{{$window.INCLUDE_FILENAME}}
<div data-ng-include="$window.INCLUDE_FILENAME"></div>
```

Above code available as a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kvPCDrSeWER8H39qpzsP)

I know that I could use a [controller storing data from `$window` as a scope variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383725/how-to-access-global-js-variable-in-angularjs-directive), but that's rather useless as I could just access it without the angular service in that case.

Comment: I don't think you can really do this, or even that you should do this.  You can add `INCLUDE_FILENAME` to the scope...

Comment: You cannot directly access global variables as angular bindings. One way you can do is this way http://plnkr.co/edit/2fXu3s?p=preview

Comment: @ExplosionPills I agree this shouldn't be done. Unfortunately, if the variable needed is only made available in the global scope, there isn't much choice.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly access global variables as a part of angular bindings in the view, since they are evaluated against the scope, in your case `$rootScope`. So basically you could add a function to the `$rootScope` on `run` of the app.

Example:-

```
angular.module('app',[]).run(['$rootScope', '$window', 
     function($rootScope, $window){
       $rootScope.getGlobals = function(variableName){
       return $window[variableName];
     };
}]);
```

and access it via this method anywhere on any scope, since any child scopes (except for isolated scopes) are descendants of `$rootScope` this method will be available to them.

```
<h1>Loading below...</h1>
{{getGlobals('INCLUDE_FILENAME')}};
<div data-ng-include="getGlobals('INCLUDE_FILENAME')"></div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HgQKcA?p=preview)**

Comment: I'm not sure what's the purpose of the `$window` service then - couldn't it just be replaced by `window` in your code?

Comment: @Razor You could. It is dependency injection. You cannot inject `window` but you could only inject `$window`. It has been added for testability... But the basic idea is that you cannot use global variables in the templates expecting that angular will evaluate it.. Well it is [right here documented](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299436/unable-to-call-object-keys-in-angularjs/25299523#25299523