# Unable to call Object.keys in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using a UI.Bootstrap accordion and I've defined my heading like so:

```html
<accordion-group ng=repeat="(cname, stations) in byClient">
    <accordion-heading>
        {{ cname }} <span class="pull-right"> {{ Object.keys(stations).length }} Stations</span>
    </accordion-heading>
```

When that displays the `Object.keys(stations).length` resolves to nothing.  If I put that same length call in my controller I get back the expected count.  Is there something preventing the method call from working in AngularJS?

The rest of the accordion that uses `stations` acts as expected, so I know that it's being populated properly.  The `byClient` data structure basically looks like so:

```js
{
    "Client Name" : {
        "Station Name": [
            {...},
            {...}
        ]
    }
 }
```

Comment: Try `{{ (stations | keys).length }} stations`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Yes, That is because `Object` is a part of `window/global` and angular cannot evaluate that expression against the scope. When you specify `Object.keys` in your binding angular tries to evaluate it against the `$scope` and it does not find it. You could store the reference of `object.keys` in some utility in rootScope and use it anywhere in the app.

Something like this:-

```
angular.module('yourApp',[deps...]).run(function($rootScope){
  //Just add a reference to some utility methods in rootscope.
  $rootScope.Utils = {
     keys : Object.keys
  }

  //If you want utility method to be accessed in the isolated Scope 
  //then you would add the method directly to the prototype of rootScope 
  //constructor as shown below in a rough implementation.

  //$rootScope.constructor.prototype.getKeys = Object.keys;

});
```

and use this as:-

```
<span class="pull-right"> {{ Utils.keys(stations).length }} Stations</span>
```

Well this will be available to any child scopes except for isolated scopes. If you are planning to do it on the isolated scope (eg:- Isolated scoped directives) you would need to add the reference of `Object.keys` on the scope, or as you expose a method on the scope which will return the length.

Or better yet , create a format filter to return the keylength and use it everywhere.

```
app.filter('keylength', function(){
  return function(input){
    if(!angular.isObject(input)){
      throw Error("Usage of non-objects with keylength filter!!")
    }
    return Object.keys(input).length;
  }
});
```

and do:-

```
{{ stations | keylength }}
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/rhvX62?p=preview)**

Comment: Just as i would have said it +1

Comment: very nice. You have given two perfect solutions! Thanks :)

Comment: If you are using an isolate scope, you will need to use `{{ $root.Utils.keys(stations).length }}`

Comment: @AJRichardson That is a very good point you made there. What you can do is instead of adding it in the rootScope instance add it to the prototype. i.e `$rootScope.constructor.prototype.getKeys  = Object.keys`. It should then be available in the isolate scope as well. Similar to what i did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274563/angularjs-communication-between-directives#answer-25274665)

Comment: why this not exists by default in Angular, is so useful !

Comment: How to use Object.keys in angularjs2.

Comment: Also I would check for undefined while passing the object  as Angular will throw a exception  `app.run(function($rootScope){   
    $rootScope.Utils =   {
        keys : function (o) {
             return Object.keys(o || {});
        } 
    };
})` , btw this is every useful.

Answer (score 4):

Use the function to determine the number of object properties:

```
$scope.keyLength = function (obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length;
}
```

and use:

```
{{ keyLength(myObj) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think **filters** are the most AngularJS way of handling structures in template code:

```
angular.module('app.filters').filter('objectKeysLength', [function() {
    return function(items) {
        return Object.keys(items).length;
    };
}]);

angular.module('app.filters').filter('objectKeys', [function() {
    return function(item) {
        if (!item) return null;
        var keys = Object.keys(item);
        keys.sort();
        return keys;
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone searches for angular 2 and higher solution. It now hat [keyvalue](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe, which can be used to interate over objects

Answer (score 0):

I could not get any of the other answers to work in AngularJS 1.6. What worked for me
using `$window` to acccess `Object.keys` like this  `$window.Object.keys({ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 })`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that worked for me :

```
export class xyzcomponent{
    Key = Object.keys;
}
```

Now in the component html file, you can use something like that :

```
<li *ngFor="let i of Key(stations)">.........</li>
```