# Object.keys is not working in Angularjs2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic2

I tried using  `<div>{{ objectkey.keys(numberOfComment['post_1']).length }} Comments</div>` in angularjs2 project but it is throwing error "cannot read property of undefined `objectkey.keys(numberOfComment['post_1']).length` " but it is working in the js (prints in the console).

i tried to implement as mentioned this link 
[Unable to call Object.keys in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299436/unable-to-call-object-keys-in-angularjs)

`this.objectkey = { keys : Object.keys }` in the js file.

`<div>{{ objectkey.keys(numberOfComment['post_1']).length }} Comments</div>` in html

Comment: The syntax is `Object.keys(obj)` - in your case probably `Object.keys(numberOfComment['post_1'])`

Comment: May i know the reason for the down votes so that i can improve myself while posting next question.

Answer (score 3):

Change to:

```
this.objectkey = { 
     keys : function(){ 
        return Object.keys(numberOfComment['post_1']).length 
     } 
}
```

and in the html

```
<div>{{ objectkey.keys() }} Comments</div>
```