# Adding a JS Variable to a AngularJS Directory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directory, angularjs-ng-include

I can't seem to get the following code to work:

```
<script>alert(topic);</script> <!-- Outputs: "dynamics" -->

<div ng-include="'content/' + topic + '.html'"></div> <!-- Does not work. -->
```

I have deduced the variable is the problem as the following code does work:

```
<div ng-include="'content/' + 'dynamics' + '.html'"></div> <!-- Works. -->
```

Does anybody know how I can do this?

**Update:**

Following Steffen's link, I have written the following code, but still no luck:

```
<script>
    alert(topic); // Outputs "dynamics"

    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
        $scope.topic = $window.topic;
    }]);
</script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-include="'content/' + 
    topic + '.html'"></div>  <!-- Does not work. -->
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383725/how-to-access-global-js-variable-in-angularjs-directive

Comment: Please remove the curly braces from ng-include attribute

Comment: use this in html : `<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-include="'content/{{topic}}.html'"></div>` OR `<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-include="'content/' + 
    topic + '.html'"></div>`

Comment: I'm sorry, but neither is working for me.

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/ursujuge/1/ You can see in the network console of your browser that it is trying to load dynamics.html

Comment: To give a bit of an explanation. The value of most angular directives (like ng-include) is evaluated as javascript in context of $scope. That is why your variable has to be declared in the current $scope. Double curly braces will lead to an error because it is not valid js syntax. Other directives like ng-href allow a string based syntax like `<a ng-href="content/{{topic}}.html">` which often leads to confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much @Steffen , after a good nights sleep I have got it to work. This has really opened my eyes to how AngularJS works as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Steffen's [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ursujuge/1/), here is how I passed a JavaScript variable to AngularJS and used it in defining a directory:

```
<script>
    // Create module.
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    // Add controller to module.
    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
        $scope.topic = $window.topic;
        console.log($scope.topic);
    }]);
</script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-include="'content/' + 
    topic + '.html'"></div> <!-- Works! -->
```

Many thanks to all for their answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<div ng-include="'content/{{topic}}.html'"></div>
```

In **angularjs** , scope `variable are access` in HTML using The *`double curly brace notation {{ }}`* .

Comment: is topic defined in your controller ?? if not thn try `$scope.topic = topic ;`  in your controller .

Comment: No,  I am trying to work out how to do this now as I am new to AngularJS. I will post an update if I can't get it to work.

Comment: try `$scope.topic = topic ;`  OR `$scope.topic = $window.topic;` in your controller .

Comment: Correct curly braces syntax would be `<a ng-href="content/{{topic}}.html">` but as far as I know ng-include requires a javascript expression as used in the code of the question. It is more likely that topic is not a scope variable as @p2. mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
<ng-include src="topic"> </ng-include>
```

Make sure you have define `$scope.topic = "whateveryouwant"`;

-----------OR-----------

You could do it like:

```
<ng-include src="getTopic()"></ng-include>
```

Controller:

```
function AppCtrl ($scope) {
  $scope.getTopic= function () {
      return 'partials/whatever.html';
  }
}
```