# accessing function scope in dom $window

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have a need to access whats in function scope[image]

This is on console.log($window);

However I am not sure whats the best way to get to that. I am eventually trying to reach to Global: window object.

Thanks

```
This is not the copy of the question above. I have read that global veriable question. Issue is that I can not get to $windows.variable and I see that variable under Global: window so I got to get to that first. But I am not sure how since its in <function scope> and I dont think I can do something like 

$window.getAllEvents.<function scope> or something
```

Comment: Are you using Angular or Angular2?  Can you elaborate on what you want to do with `$window!`?

Comment: `$window` is reference to global `window`

Comment: I am using angularjs not angular2. I want to get some DOM data that has been in the DOM from non angular application.

Comment: if I do $window.myDOMVariable  it says undefined. but if I do console.log($window) I see it under Global.Window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access global js variable in AngularJS directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383725/how-to-access-global-js-variable-in-angularjs-directive) ... follow the example here

Comment: I looked at that example and its not working for me...like I said I get undefind...I think I would have to loop or something

Comment: This is not the copy of the question above. I have read that global veriable question. Issue is that I can not get to $windows.variable and I see that variable under Global: window so I got to get to that first. But I am not sure how since its in <function scope> and I dont think I can do something like 

$window.getAllEvents.<function scope> or something