# How to access AngularJS scope variable from template script using $window

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am able to successfully access the javascript variable in my AngularJs controller using the `$window` service, by learning from this answer [how to access global js variables in angularjs directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383725/how-to-access-global-js-variable-in-angularjs-directive).

Here is a code pen to demonstrate what I mean: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/lznxe

I want to achieve the opposite, that is accessing `$window.variable` in my template javascript.

I tried doing this. However, the alert box only shows the output:

> Undefined

**Template Javascript:**

```
<script>
   alert(window.globalVar);
</script>
```

**AngularJS Controller:**

```
 app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$http,$interval,$window){
     $window.globalVar="test";
 )};
```

Here is a code pen to demonstrate the problem that I am describing: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgqNBa

How can I achieve what I want? The main goal is to access the `$scope` variable to be used in the **Template Javascript**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is `alert(window.globalVar);` get's run before `$window.globalVar="test";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the script in the `<script>` tags get executed too early. With a `setTimeout` of `1000` it seems to work. Try to add an `onLoad` on your `<body>` tag, so your script gets executed after the variable is defined.

Comment: Which function did you set the Timeout to?

Comment: I waited 1000ms before triggering `alert(window.globalVar);`. But don't rely on the timeout, that's bad practice; I only used it to confirm what @George said in the comment on your question.