# Access to global variables through console in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As I understand from this question [Global variables in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938380/global-variables-in-angularjs) I have got basically 2 options for "global" variables:

- use a $rootScope http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope
- use a service http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

So, for example, I have `$rootScope.myVar`. How can I get it through the console? Like if `myVar` is an object with some methods and I need to call one of its method.

Comment: Why exactly do you need this? "Global" on the root scope still doesn't mean "global" in Javascript scope. And calling things from outside Angular is… weird at best.

Comment: @deceze I understand that, so there is no way to get access to this variables, yes? Only if I make them "global" in javasript and outside the angularjs?

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't be doing that… again: what for? Purely for debugging you can set breakpoints in your browser's debugger and evaluate any expression is any scope.

Comment: If you want to access a variable in angularjs that is in javascripts scope, then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383725/how-to-access-global-js-variable-in-angularjs-directive

Comment: @Vivz Thanks, thats what I've asked!