# How to make a multiplication between a twig variable and an angularjs variable

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, twig

I want to do it quickly without controller if possible.

[image]

I have a twig template where I can access a variable: price. Here, for example, the price is equal to 150.
I create a select with 5 options as below. And I want to have the total but I have a "Warning: A non-numeric value encountered".

```
<select name="total" ng-model="total">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
${{ price }}
${{ '{{ total }}' * price }}
```

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the value of price  in a js var and use it in angular

```
<script>
var myPrice="{{phpPrice}}";
</script>
```

Than perform your calc.

Comment: It's works, but I need to create a scope variable and a controller like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383725/how-to-access-global-js-variable-in-angularjs-directive)